# Check multiple vars if undefined

Tags: javascript

## Idea

I want to check more params if they are `undefined`. It would work if I do something like this:

```
if(param1 === undefined || param2 === undefined || param3 === undefined) {
    console.log('Is missing');
}
```

But I've 6+ params and it would be nice if I could do something like this:

```
if((param1 || param2 || param3) === undefined) {
    console.log('Is missing');
}
```

## Problem

The second code part will not return 'Is missing' if for example param3 is undefined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an array with `.some`:

```
if ([param1, param2, param3].some(e => e === undefined)) {
    console.log("Is missing");
}
```

Comment: I write now a method with your code. Works very well thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

With if statement, undefined equals false.

```js
var param1, param2, param3 = undefined;

if(!param1 || !param2 || !param3) {
    console.log('Is missing');
}
```

Comment: This might not work as expected, one of the parameters could equal `false` or `0`

Comment: True that. Passing `false` or `0` will not work as expected.

However, there is nothing wrong with this approach.

Comment: This approach is OK if you know that the defined values will be truthy, e.g. the parameters always contain object. It doesn't work for more general cases.